# Visual Studio - C# project appearing with C++ Syntax

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio 2015 community installation is suddenly displaying C# concepts on the VS GUI in a C++-style syntax. For example, this is a brand new C# app on .Net framework 4.5.2:
[Note the way the class name is shown in the stack frame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8hyD.png)

It is also displaying class names with a caret (^) character suffix, and showing "nullptr" for null objects instead of "null" (in preview windows).

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? I was happily coding this app without any weird behavior until about half an hour ago. This behavior also occurs for applications with no recent changes made to them, so I can only assume I hit a strange key combination in Visual Studio and changed a setting by mistake.

Here is an example stack trace. Note how the "Language" column shows "C++":
[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBcK6.png)

Comment: First time I've heard of this problem happening in that direction, usually it's the reverse.  Can you grab a screenshot of the actual "Call Stack" debug window, which has a "Language" column?

Comment: @MethodMan: He said it was working normally up until 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @BenVoigt the question has been updated with a stack trace image

Comment: That's weird, it is really C++/CLI syntax, you should sent the screenshot to MS

Comment: Ok, so that confirms it thinks you are working in C++ (which makes the rest of the behavior correct -- all the displays are matching the working language).  It seems rather difficult to find information about debugger language mis-detection, since it gets lost in the "English vs non-English debugger UI" kind of language.

Comment: Does a project full-rebuild help?  If you look at the debugger modules window, does it show that debug information is correctly found for your assembly?

Comment: BTW, you have two projects, a class library and a console application.  Are both of them C#, or is the one C# and the other C++?

Comment: I removed and reinstall VS and all frameworks, then reinstalled. Now the compiler is moaning when I try to build: "Visual C# 2015 Compiler Could Not Be Created". Sadly I am going to format this machine and use my old laptop in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working after trying every single solution I could find from Google searches. The steps that seem to have fixed it:

1. Completely remove VS 2015 Community
2. Complete re-install of VS 2015 Community
3. The registry fix here: [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1615183/setsite-failed-for-package-image-service-package), specifically the section on the "0xfffffffe2e276b55" registry key.